# How to make size of <svg> equal to size of <path> without modifying <path>?

Tags: html, css, svg, icons

Currently, the width and height of the svg is 48px and path is 40px. How to make their sizes equal?

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.container svg {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="black" width="1em" height="1em">
        <path d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm-2 14.5v-9l6 4.5-6 4.5z"></path>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `viewBox` attribute in the `svg` element

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.container svg {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <svg viewBox="2 2 20 20" fill="black" width="1em" height="1em">
        <path d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm-2 14.5v-9l6 4.5-6 4.5z"></path>
    </svg>
</div>
```